# A group of related PHP functions: what is the most acceptable way to organize them?

Tags: php, oop

This might be a stupid question but I have to ask:

I have a big group of related functions for a project I am doing. The functions need to access a few global variables, so I was thinking about putting them into a class and loading the class as needed. I suppose my other option is to just include them as unrelated functions in an included PHP file, but putting them into 1 class *seems* to make sense. Is this an acceptable practice? I have worked with people who did this but it always seemed to not quite be in the spirit of good OOP practices because the classes were almost never instantiated but the functions were still called. Or maybe I'm over thinking it.

Any input would be awesome, thanks a bunch.

Comment: `The functions need to access a few global variables` - delete them and create new, without global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class does make the most sense. Whenever you can eliminate global variables, it is a good thing. Whether the class is instantiated or a static helper usually depends on the context. However, for future unit testing, instantiations allow [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Answer (score 0):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29, a class defines constituent members which enable class instances to have state and behavior. If you will be providing only behavior (functions) and not state (properties), you should include your functions in an include file and forgo the overhead of a class.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but this seems like you should create a class that acts as a static service, where no explicit instantiation is needed of the class, yet you will still call the methods contained within this class.

Now, if you're thinking of storing those global variables in the class, obviously that's no longer a static class because there would have to be some sort of lifetime for the object, and at which point you'd have to instantiate the class first and then make calls to those methods.

Regardless, if they're all related functions working on the same data, it certainly makes sense to group them within their own class.